# DataTable column name with Double Quotes in the ColumName and generating a SQL column without it

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to allow a user to enter a column (Cell B2) in an excel file as **"GameLength"** and then remove the double quotes on the front and end to then generate a column for a database as **GameLength**

[image]

I am able to update the column to be **GameLength** without any issues.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[123](
      [PTIKeyId] [integer] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

      [Game Number] [int] NULL,
      [Game Length] [int] NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_123] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
      [PTIKeyId] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY])
```

When I get to the code to cycle the datatable rows I'm seeing this error:

```
Column '"Game Length"' does not belong to table .
```

Here is the line of code it is failing on:

[image]

It appears my item text is correct, but maybe a data table cannot process it?

What are my options?

I'm really wanting to remove the double quotes from the destination field and basically let the code function without telling the end user to go to the file and remove the double quotes before proceeding.

I can't seem to figure out why it can't find **"GameLength"** in the data table?

Here is the foreach loop to cycle the data table rows:

SourceFields are the columns that are from the data table

```
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTableResults.Rows)
            {
                sbInsert.Clear();

                // create start insert statement with the proper columns that will be used.
                sbInsert.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "INSERT INTO [{0}].[{1}]", schemaName, tableName).AppendLine();
                sbInsert.Append("(");
                foreach (var item in destinationFields.Where(w => w != PrimaryKeyId))
                {
                    sbInsert.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "[{0}], ", item);
                }

                // set to - 2 because we are adding ', ' (comma then a space for readability)
                sbInsert.Remove(sbInsert.Length - 2, 1);

                // Now create the actual values
                sbInsert.Append(")").AppendLine();
                sbInsert.Append("VALUES").AppendLine();
                sbInsert.Append("(");

                foreach (var item in sourceFields)
                {
                    var cellValue = row[item];
                    var dataMappingRecord = dataMappings.Where(w => w.SourceFieldName == item).FirstOrDefault();

                    sbInsert.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}", GetCellValue(dataMappingRecord, cellValue, dataTypes));
                }

                // set to - 2 because we are adding ', ' (comma then a space for readability)
                sbInsert.Remove(sbInsert.Length - 2, 1);
                sbInsert.Append(");");
            }
```

How I populate the SourceFields:

```
        private async Task<IList<DataMappingDTO>> GenerateCreateNewTableDataMappings(Workbook workbook, FileDetailDTO fileDetail)
        {
            var sourceFields = await GetSourceFields(workbook, fileDetail, false).ConfigureAwait(false);

            foreach (var item in sourceFields)
            {
                // add code to remove any double quotes in the column name for the destination file
                string destinationFieldUpdated = item.ColumnName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);

                if (fileDetail.DataMappings.Any(a => a.SourceFieldName.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) == item.ColumnName.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)) == false)
                {
                    var mapping = new DataMappingDTO
                    {
                        Index = item.ColumnIndex,
                        ImportDetailId = fileDetail.ImportDetailId,
                        ImportData = true,
                        SourceFieldName = item.ColumnName,
                        DestinationFieldName = destinationFieldUpdated,
                        DataType = item.DataType,
                        Precision = item.Precision ?? null,
                        ColumnLength = item.DataType == GetDataTypeList().Where(w => w.ImporterDataTypes == ImporterDataTypes.StringDT).Select(s => s.Id).FirstOrDefault() ? 255 : (int?)null,
                        Format = GetFormatTypeFromSourceField(item)
                    };

                    mapping.UpdateModifiedInfo(UserRequestingId);
                    fileDetail.DataMappings.Add(mapping);
                }
            }

            return fileDetail.DataMappings;
        }
```

Comment: How do you populate the soucefields collection? Also did you notice that there is a space in `Game Length`? Is it expected?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I added the code for source fields. I do see the space now! I do not see it in the file though! Let me check the code again and debug.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: I posted my answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ChetanRanpariya

There was a space at the start:

[image]

I went to the excel document and totally deleted everything in B2. Then I went back in and put

```
"Game Length"
```

and everything worked!!!

Thanks again.